# WP Get IDs of parent categories only

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

The snippet below works fine but I've hard coded **the parent categories IDs**, Now I'm looking for a way to get rid of hard coded IDs.

```
      <div class="row">
                    <?php
                     $catsArray = array(176, 175); // This line need to be dynamic and the IDs are parent categories.
                      $categories = get_terms(
                              array(
                          'hide_empty' => false,
                          'include' => $catsArray, 'orderby'  => 'include'

                      ) );

                      foreach ($categories as $key => $cat) {
        
                      $cat_thumb_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );



                      $term_link = get_category_link( $cat->term_id );
                     ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="sellers-wrap is-revealing">
                        <figure>
                          <img src="<?php echo $cat_img; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                        </figure>
                        <div class="sellers-text">
                            <p><strong><?php echo $cat->name; ?></strong></p>
                          
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 <?php } ?>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If 0 is passed, only top-level terms are returned.**

```
$categories = get_terms( 
 'category', 
 array('parent' => 0)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter you have to get_terms is an array of arguments. All possible values are documented here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/ . It sounds like you just want to get all categories that are at the top level of the hierarchy (i.e. have no parent). So to do that you can just use the 'parent' argument and pass 0. Like this:

```
$categories = get_terms([
    'hide_empty'    => false,
    'parent'        => 0
]);
```

Comment: It prints all categories on the page. I had replace your block of code but it did not work.

Comment: How are your categories setup? The original post seemed to suggest that the two IDs you have hard-coded there are the only ones that are parents? Is that not the case? If so - the above should work.

Comment: I've only two parent categories and many subcategories, in my own code when I print_r($cat); it shows me the two parent categories in right way. 
But when I replace the snippet you provide and then print_r($cat); it shows too many   WP_Term Objects.

Comment: What are the other WP_Term objects coming back? It would be useful to cross reference those. I'm not sure what taxonomy you're trying to pull for here - it may be that you're expecting this to return only terms of a specific taxonomy, but you're getting others? The arguments array accepts a taxonomy as well. I would suggest you look through the link above in the answer.

Comment: Thanks let me take a look and I think you are right it sounds like I just want to get all categories that are at the top level of the hierarchy.